# How to include a external php file outsie the zend application folder in .phtml view

Tags: zend-framework

I need to include external php file(outside the zend application path ) in zend .phtml file

Project structure

```
Project1

--->zend application

--->php file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can changing `composer.json` (changing require by adding this kind of code change) file to:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "../file_name.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Or if that file is php class itself, then:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "../CustomClass.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Main thing is to point file location relatively to `composer.json` file location.